# Help needed in Unit 5 Section 1 Algebra by Hungerford

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, problem-solving

I am self studying Field Theory from Textbook Hungerford and couldn't solve this problem on page 241 .

[image]

For (a)  X would be composite of LM if X = intersection of all subfields P such that  $L\bigcap M\subseteq P$.

So, I tried using this defination to prove  $LM \subseteq  L(S) $ and $L(S) \subseteq LM$.

I tried proving $LM \subseteq L(S) $but I got confused by inclusion relations as K is subset of $ L \bigcap M $ and then M= K(S) for some S subset of M.

It's a very hard nut to crack due to it and I am unable to.

I have done (b).

For (c) I have no clue. (a) can't be used in C as $E_i$ can't be necessarily subset of each other,in my opinion.

So, can you please tell how to solve (a) and Give hint for (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a), your definition of the composition $LM$ seems to be wrong. The definition of $LM$ is the the smallest subfield containing *both* $L$ and $M$, not the intersection $L\cap M$.

First note that $L(S) \supset K(S) =M$ (because $L\supset K$). Clearly $L\subset L(S)$. So $LM \subset L(S)$. On the other hand, $L(S) \subset (LM)(S) = LM$ since $L\subset LM$ and $S\subset M$.

Part c), you can prove inductively on $n$. (Try prove the case for $n=2$ first.)

Comment: we don't have $ K \subset L$!!

Comment: Isn't $K\subset L\cap M$?

Comment: it is never written in the question.

Comment: The first line of part a) literally says 'If $K\subset L\cap M$... ' are we reading the same question?